# Workbook, which contains a clock, automatically reopens

Tags: excel, vba

I've got three Subs in Module: runClock, startClock and stopClock.

- `runClock` is showing a clock that is updated every 5 seconds.
- `startClock` is used to start the clock and is called from `Sub Workbook_Open`.
- `stopClock` - is used to stop the clock and is called from `Sub Workbook_BeforeClose`.

However, when ever I close the workbook, it reopens automatically and the clock continues to run. I've checked the value of ClockOn and it's set to `FALSE` after the Workbook_BeforeClose is executed. I think that that issue has to do with `Application.OnTime`, but don't know how to fix it.

This Code is in Module:

```
Global ClockOn As Boolean

Sub runClock()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        If ClockOn = True Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5), "runClock"
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub startClock()
    ClockOn = True
    runClock
End Sub

Sub stopClock()
    ClockOn = False
End Sub
```

This Code is in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    stopClock
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    startClock
End Sub
```

Comment: "However, when ever I close the workbook, it reopens automatically and the clock continues to run." - this is really strange. Can you reboot your PC (not joking), open only that Excel file, then close it and see whether it will open again?

Comment: It reopens (I reboot and opened only that Excel workbook). The only way to stop it from reopening is by closing the application. It seems that the reopening is related to the clock update intervals. Now it's 5 seconds so the workbook reopens almost immediately. If, for example, I would change the update interval to 20 seconds, it will take longer time for the workbook to reopen.

Comment: Another way to stop the workbook from reopening is by running sub stopClock, waiting for the clock to update one more time and then closing the workbook. This is way I think that it's has to do with Application.OnTime

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening because the times resulting from Application.OnTime are not the same. The initial call time should be saved as a variable and then referenced in the subs.  See this solution.

https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/131658-timer-reopens-workbook-when-closed

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

I've changed my sub stopClock so now it includes the following code:

```
RunWhen = Now + timeserial(0, 0, 5)
Application.OnTime earliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:="startClock", Schedule:=False
```

This stops the clock from running and the workbook from reopening.

I don't know what caused it to reopen under the previous code, but at least now it's fine.